# In Perl, how can I import a hash from a library?

Tags: perl, hash, scope, perl-module

I have a file `revs.pm`:

```
my %vers = ( foo => "bar" );
```

And another file like `importer.pl`:

```
use revs;
```

How can I access `%vers` from `importer.pl` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create a proper module and change the [my](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html) keyword to [our](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html):

```
# revs.pm
package revs;

our %vers = ( foo => "bar" );

1; # Perl modules need to return a boolean "true" value.

# importer.pl
use revs;

print $revs::vers{foo} . "\n";
```

Comment: Surely, you meant to say `our %vers` instead of `my %vers`. :-P

Comment: Keep in mind that global variables are evil, so using an accessor method might be better. :)

Answer (score 9):

Another conventional way is to use the [Exporter](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html) module in your [package](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/package.html), and export the variable:

```
package revs;
use strict;
use warnings;
require Exporter;
our @ISA    = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT = qw(%vers);
our %vers   = (foo=>'bar');
1;
```

This avoids having to use the package name when referring to the variable from `importer.pl`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use revs;
print Dumper(\%vers);
```

One disadvantage is that you must make sure your variable name is unique in order to avoid name collisions.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, you could just not couple parts of your program with a
global variable.  Consider what happens when you use this hash in one module:

```
package Foo;
use MyApp::Versions qw(%versions); # i'm going to pretend that you didn't call the module "revs".

some_function {
    while(my ($k, $v) = each %versions){
       return if $some_condition;
    }
}
```

And then in some other module:

```
package Bar;
use MyApp::Versions qw(%versions);

some_other_function {
    while(my ($k, $v) = each %versions){
       print "$k => $v\n";
    }
}
```

And then use both modules:

```
use Foo;
use Bar;

some_other_function;
some_function;
some_other_function;
```

Depending on `$some_condition`, some_other_function produces different
results each time you call it.  Have fun debugging that.  (This is
more of an `each` problem than a global state problem; but by exposing
the internal implementation, you allow your callers to do things that
you didn't intend, and that can easily break your program.)

It's also a pain to rewrite Foo and Bar when you change the hard-coded
hash to an on-demand database lookup, for example.

So the real solution is to design a proper API, and export that
instead of the entire variable:

```
package MyApp::Versions;
use strict;
use Carp qw(confess);
use Sub::Exporter -setup => {
    exports => ['get_component_version'],
};

my %component_versions = ( foo => 42 ); # yes, "my", not "our".

sub get_component_version {
    my ($component) = @_;
    return $component_versions{$component} ||
        confess "No component $component!"
}

1;
```

Now your module is easier to use:

```
package Foo;
use MyApp::Versions qw(get_component_version);

sub some_function {
    die 'your foo is too old'
        unless get_component_version('foo') >= 69;

    return FooComponent->oh_hai;
}
```

Now some_function can't mess up some_other_function, and when you
change the implementation of get_component_version, the rest of your
program won't care.

Comment: +1. It seems people are eager to vote for the hard and fast solution over best practices.